# Time count based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

I've been trying hard to figure this one out, see if anyone could give me some directions, please.

I have a worksheet in which I put the activities performed through the day (column W), so I have a report for every day. Each activity has a type defined by a letter listed in a drop down menu (column U), for example: 'R' for *'Reporting'*, 'M' for *'Meeting'* etc, and a duration in hours (HH:mm) (column S).

What I want my worksheet to do is to sum all the durations of the activities based on their type and store the results in a diferent cell. In the image example attached, I'd have to have 3:30 h for *Meeting*, 4:30 for *Reporting* and 2 h for *Drawing*.

What the following SumIf code does is to sum all the hours, but it is not acounting for the duration, once the duration is the difference between the time in the next row and the time of the row in which the conditional argument is.

```
Sub test_count_hours()

Range("E35").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("U8:U37"), "R", Range("S8:S37"))

End Sub
```

So my struggle is to make the code acounting for the duration of the events.

Example of a filled Worksheet

[image]

Comment: If you need help with your code, please include it in your question.

Comment: You need `SumIf`, but please, a @braX mentioned, post your code or what you have tried until now.

Comment: You're correct @Moacir, I've edited my question, I just thought it is too simple to even include it, but I was wrong.

Comment: Now you just need to make it loop through all unique code values, to make it you can use `x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, c)` and the condition can be `If x = 1 Then 'do the sumif'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing your activity types in an array? You can loop through each activity and then loop through each row to check the activity type, adding the time between that and the next row if it's a match

```
Sub sumHours()
Dim activityList As Variant
Dim activity As Variant
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim countHours As Date

activityList = Array("M", "R", "Dv")

Range("U5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count

For Each activity In activityList
countHours = 0
    For i = 5 To rowCount + 5
        If Range("U" & i) = activity Then
            countHours = countHours + Range("S" & i + 1) - Range("S" & i)
        End If
    Next i

    Select Case activity
        Case Is = "M"
        Range("E35") = countHours

        Case Is = "R"
        Range("E36") = countHours

        Case Is = "Dv"
        Range("E37") = countHours
    End Select
Next activity
End Sub
```

(Make sure the cells that will hold the timevalues are formatted with the "Time" data type.

Comment: It looks like your activities start on row 5. If not you would change the initial cell selected :)

Comment: Thank you, @Leroy, that is exactly what I needed! Thanks to all the other as well, off course.